# No deadlock in ASP.NET MVC on Mono

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mono

There is classical example of deadlock in ASP.NET MVC by Stephen Cleary https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Here is simplified example

```
public ActionResult Deadlock()
{
    StartWork().Wait();

    return View();
}

private async Task StartWork()
{
    await Task.Delay(100).ConfigureAwait(true);
}
```

But when I try to reproduce it on my Mac with Mono 5.20.1.19, it does not show up.

Does it mean that Mono treats `SynchronizationContext` somehow different or does not has any?